# How to set focus to a textedit on buttonclick in C# Winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress

I need to set focus to a textedit on Button Click event ? in my Form
i tried this one but not working `TXE_FlatDiscountP.Focus();` How to set focus on event ?

Comment: It works unless `textbox` is disabled

Comment: your idea should work could you please post your code for the buttonclick event handler maybe your just doing it wrong

Comment: Please post the code you are using in the ButtonEvent. Normaly the .Focus() Method should working like Shaharyar described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your way is correct. Maybe you are missing something.To be more detailed here is an example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Focus();
        }
```

This is an example of setting focus to a textbox.

Comment: Hi, This code work fine but when I click button it focused on that particular textedit as read only mode that I cont able to edit that value. If I click out side of text box then only it come back to normal.